# Cannot Create A Directory Called 'partition' On msdos Flashdrive

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, mkdir

Really strange issue that I've encountered.

I have fedora 23 and a flash drive that I play with writing some scripts for mount/unmount operations:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /run/media/mymounts/kol type msdos (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,
dmask=0022,codepage=437,errors=remount-ro)
```

Trying to run mkdir partiti**on** within kol creates a directory called partiti**o**. An attempt to run the same command again gives:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘partition’: File exists
```

An attempt to create a partiti**o** directory first, and then to run mkdir partition gives the same error as above.

Remounting does not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: 8.3 is an important thing to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOS filesystem only supports a maximum filename length of 8 characters, plus an optional dot and extension of up to three characters.

When you asked it to create `partition`, it only used the first 8 characters to give you `partitio`.

Running the command again, it tried to create another `partitio` directory but it already existed, despite the confusing `'partition': File exists` message.